# Create a Meta Box in the Admin User Screen?

Tags: admin, metabox, user-registration

My client wants the New User admin page to be composed of a meta box.

```
add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context, $priority, $callback_args );
```

But this seems to be for posts only (`$post_type`).
Is there an alternative for the User screen?

Comment: This article, http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/integrating-with-wordpress-ui-meta-boxes-on-custom-pages/ should help you. From member @Stephen Harris [profile](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9364/stephen-harris)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Well, as you already know, meta boxes are for post types [only](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)...</strike>

What you can do is to customize the heck out of that screen.

What follows is the code I used on a client's custom theme.
<sub>Originally, it was used with the action hook `admin_print_scripts-profile.php` (which could also be added bellow).</sub>

#### `/functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-user-new.php', 'wpse_66477_customize_profile' );

function wpse_66477_customize_profile() {
    wp_register_style( 'wpse_66477_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/profile.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse_66477_css' );
    wp_register_script( 'wpse_66477_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/profile.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse_66477_js' );
}
```

#### `/css/profile.css`:

```
#contextual-help-link-wrap { display: none !important; }

description,h2,h3,#icon-profile,#icon-users,#ozhmenu_wrap,.editform {
display:none
}

#your-profile {
width:485px;
padding:15px
}

body {
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:10px;
color:#ccc
}

#wpbody-content {
width:500px;
background-color:#fff;
border:1px solid #C3C3C3;
margin:20px 20%;
padding:0 30px 0 0
}

#wpwrap {
display:none;
background-color:#F6F6F6
}

.form-table th {
width:120px;
text-align:right
}

p.help,p.description,span.description,.form-wrap p {
font-size:9px;
font-family:Verdana
}

.description {
line-height:11px
}

input.button-primary,button.button-primary,a.button-primary {
border:0;
font-weight:normal;
color:black;
background:#6EAC51;
text-shadow:none;
height:17px
}

.form-table td {
margin-bottom:9px;
line-height:9px;
font-size:10px;
padding:0 10px
}

.submit {
border:0;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto
}

.submit input,.button,input.button,.button-primary,input.button-primary,.button-secondary,input.button-secondary,.button-highlighted,input.button-highlighted,#postcustomstuff .submit input {
-webkit-border-radius:0!important;
border-radius:0!important;
padding:5px 25px
}

#pass-strength-result {
margin-top:3px
}

#pass1 {
margin-top:5px
}
```

#### `/js/profile.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $("#wpwrap").fadeIn(1500);  
    $("#display_name").parents("tr").hide();
    $("#nickname").parents("tr").hide();
    $("#url").parents("tr").hide();
    $("#password .description").css("display","inline");    
    $('#wpbody-content').prepend('<div style="margin-left: 141px; padding-top: 20px;"><img src="http://example.com/img/logo.png" alt="Site logo, goes to main page" title="" width="240" height="80"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Nice answer, quick correction meta boxes are not for post types only.

Comment: @Bainternet, I doubted before writing that... thx for the feedback.

Comment: You can as well use the `post.js` file. That one enables nearly everything in the admin UI.

Comment: @kaiser, dankeschon, duly noted!